# How to display the selected phone contacts in uitextview in my app ..?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return contactName.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

}    cell.textLabel.text = [contactName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSDictionary *number = [mobileNo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [number valueForKey:@"mobile"];
return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        NSLog(@"Wait");
    }
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

UITableViewCell *tablecell1=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

BOOL isselected=(tablecell1.accessoryType==UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark);
if (isselected) {
    tablecell1.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}else
{
    tablecell1.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}


  }

//done button action performs copy the contacts from phone to uitextview .
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 NSArray *indexSelected = [yourtableview indexPathsForSelectedRows];
 NSMutableString *strPhoneNumbers = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@""];
   for (NSIndexPath *index in indexSelected) {

      NSString *name = [contactName objectAtIndex: index.row];
      NSDictionary *number = [mobileNo objectAtIndex:index.row];
      NSString *number = [number valueForKey:@"mobile"];
      NSString *contactInfo = [name stringByAppendingString: number];
      [strPhoneNumbers appendString:[contactInfo stringByAppendingString:@"\n"]];

    }
    youtextView.text =  strPhoneNumbers;
```

try with this hope it will useful to you